# c++ pointer to member function using std::function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pointers

I know this has been asked multiple times, most of the answers are difficult for me to understand. 
Could you please help me in figuring out what am I doing wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

class A{
    public:
        A(double i){
            _b = i;
        }
        double square(double i){

            return i*i*_b;
        }


    private:
    double _i;
    double _b;
};

double cube(double (*objfunc)(double), double x){
    return objfunc(x)*x;   
}

int main()
{
    double v = 2.0;
    A a(v);

    using std::placeholders::_1;
    std::function<double(double)> f_square = std::bind( &A::square, &a, _1 );
    double x = cube(f_square,3.0);
    std::cout << " x = " << x << std::endl;


}
```

Thank you as always for your advice.

Given the class A and the cube function as they are how can I use the cube function in the main function ?

*Update: Only way to do this would be to modify:*

```
double cube(std::function<double(double)> objfunc, double x){
    return objfunc(x)*x;   
}
```

Comment: You are trying to pass `std::function` instance where a plain function pointer is expected. The former is not convertible to the latter.

Comment: Could you please help me modifying the main function such that it works. Whats the proper way of using the function square ?

Comment: I think it can not be done as member function pointer are not simple pointers. But I have very limited understanding. So lets wait for experts to come in.

Comment: You cannot modify only `main` and make it work: the square peg won't fit into a round hole, no matter how hard you push. You could modify `cube` to take `std::function<double(double)>` parameter.

Comment: I agree. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `cube` take an `std::function` object instead of a function pointer.  Also get rid of the `std::bind` and use a lambda together with the magic of `auto`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
public:
  A(double i) : _b(i) {}
  double square(double i) { return i*i*_b; }
private:
  double _b;
};

double cube(std::function<double(double)> objfunc, double x)
{
  return objfunc(x)*x;   
}

int main()
{
  double v = 2.0;
  A a(v);

  auto f_square = [&a] ( double x ) { return a.square(x); };
  double x = cube(f_square,3.0);
  std::cout << " x = " << x << std::endl;
}
```